# How to deploy worker to elastic beanstalk?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There are plenty of examples of deploying a webserver to benastalk, but I can't seem to find an example of deploying a worker to beanstalk.

I'm trying to deploy a ruby worker running inside a docker container.

Comment: while deploying your code,do you have .ebextension file which contain list of workers code?...What you tried??

Comment: tbh, i'm just very new to all this and very confused. I'm following this: https://github.com/embrace-io/eb-sqs-docker-dispatch

Comment: do you upload `DockerFile` and `Dockerrun.aws.json`.Is Docker install in EBS already?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I've created a docker image that, when run, immediately starts the worker process and it works. However, there is no port to expose, and when I upload it to EBS, I don't see anything in the logs or at the endpoint url to indicate that it's working.